# Iptables - Can't get get my custom SNAT rules to work

Tags: iptables, nat, ubuntu-22.04

Simply, I have two networks one for docker and another one for Libvirt. I need to let one container from the docker network to reach out all VMs in the Libvirt network. So, I added an SNAT rule to match any packet sourced from "172.17.0.4" (container IP) and destined to "192.168.122.0/24" (libvirt network) and targeted those packets to be SNATed as follow

```
sudo iptables -t NAT -I POSTROUTING 1 -s 172.17.0.4 -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j SNAT --to 192.168.122.1
```

But, unfortunately, when I tried to send some echos, none of the packets matched the rule and I get "Destination Port Unreachable" error at the docker level and the packets never reach any of the VMs.

After investigating this, I found the below chain in the filter table created by libvirt:

```
Chain LIBVIRT_FWO (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.121.0/24     anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port- 
unreachable
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Here's the output of ip route command from the container:

```
default via 172.17.0.1 dev eth0 
172.17.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.4
```

any ideas?

Comment: Please add output of `ip route` from inside the container to the question.

Comment: I've edited the question with the output of ip route from the container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an unknown reason, I found the below entry in iptables filter table

```
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -o virbr1 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

After deleting it, I can access the libvirt network from the docker container without any issues.

Thanks Tero and Larsks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need any custom NAT rules.

Traffic exiting the containers will hit the `MASQUERADE` rule that Docker installs for the network (e.g., `-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE`), so your virtual machines will see traffic originating from the libvirt bridge (`192.168.122.1`).

### Configuration

I have a Docker container named `example-container` attached to `docker0`:

```
$ docker ps
[...]
0ddd3554466b   alpine                         "/bin/sh"                5 seconds ago   Up 4 seconds                                                                                             example-container
```

That container has the following network configuration:

```
/ # ip addr show eth0
2642: eth0@if2643: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP,M-DOWN> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.2/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fdc9:87ad:f15:5bea:0:242:ac11:2/64 scope global flags 02
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:acff:fe11:2/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I have virtual machine named `example-vm` attached to the libvirt `default` network:

```
$ virsh list
 Id   Name         State
----------------------------
 2    example-vm   running
```

The virtual machine has the following network configuration:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ip addr show eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:30:7b:a6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp1s0
    inet 192.168.122.70/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 3548sec preferred_lft 3548sec
    inet6 fe80::2ccd:72ed:1fea:ccda/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

### From the container to the vm

From inside the container, I am able to `ping` the virtual machine:

```
/ # ping -c2 192.168.122.70
PING 192.168.122.70 (192.168.122.70): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.122.70: seq=0 ttl=63 time=0.262 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.122.70: seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.286 ms

--- 192.168.122.70 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.262/0.274/0.286 ms
```

If I run `tcpdump` inside the virtual machine while doing this, I see:

```
[root@localhost ~]# tcpdump -i eth0 -n icmp
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
07:23:38.661246 IP 192.168.122.1 > 192.168.122.70: ICMP echo request, id 9, seq 0, length 64
07:23:38.661277 IP 192.168.122.70 > 192.168.122.1: ICMP echo reply, id 9, seq 0, length 64
07:23:39.661247 IP 192.168.122.1 > 192.168.122.70: ICMP echo request, id 9, seq 1, length 64
07:23:39.661261 IP 192.168.122.70 > 192.168.122.1: ICMP echo reply, id 9, seq 1, length 64
```

### From the vm to the container

Similarly, I can ping the container from the virtual machine:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ping -c2 172.17.0.2
PING 172.17.0.2 (172.17.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.17.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.149 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.127 ms

--- 172.17.0.2 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1035ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.127/0.138/0.149/0.011 ms
```

And `tcpdump` in the container shows:

```
/ # tcpdump -i eth0 -n
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
12:24:48.690361 IP 172.17.0.1 > 172.17.0.2: ICMP echo request, id 2, seq 1, length 64
12:24:48.690373 IP 172.17.0.2 > 172.17.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 2, seq 1, length 64
12:24:49.723189 IP 172.17.0.1 > 172.17.0.2: ICMP echo request, id 2, seq 2, length 64
12:24:49.723204 IP 172.17.0.2 > 172.17.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 2, seq 2, length 64
```

### Netfilter rules

This works because Docker installs the following rule:

```
host# iptables -t nat -S POSTROUTING
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
[...]
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
[...]
```

When traffic exits the container, it hits the `MASQUERADE` rule. Since the libvirt `virbr0` interface is the egress interface for that packet, it gets rewritten to the address of the bridge, which is why in the `tcpdump` output in the vm we see the `ping` requests originating from 192.168.122.1.

Similarly, `libvirt` installs the following rules:

```
host# iptables -t nat -S LIBVIRT_PRT
[...]
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
[...]
```

These accomplish the same thing; requests from the virtual machine to the container get rewritten to the address of the `docker0` bridge.

Comment: I know this, but for an unknown reason all packets originating from my docker container destined to libvirt network got rejected with a port unreachable icmp reply. Adding those custom rules was a give up step because I wasn't know the reason of blocking.

Comment: If you're getting a "port unreachable" message, that suggests either a routing problem or a firewall rule issue. Running `tcpdump` on your host -- looking at the Docker bridge and the libvirt bridge -- can help narrow down the scope of the problem. Similarly, if you have custom firewall rules configured, removing them and seeing if that impacts the behavior is a good place to start.